# Outer product with arrays of multiple dimensions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have `d` numpy arrays of shape `(2, s, t, ...)`, and I'd like to multiply each of them with each other such that the output has shape `(2, ..., 2, s, t, ...)` with `d` `2`s. For example, with `d==3`:

```
import numpy

d = 3
a = numpy.random.rand(d, 2, 7, 8)

out = numpy.empty((2, 2, 2, 7, 8))
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
        for k in range(2):
            out[i, j, k] = a[0][i]*a[1][j]*a[2][k]
```

If `s, t, ...` is not present (which is also a use case), this is classical outer product.

I thought about [`meshgrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) but can't quite get it to work.

Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following method computes the d-outer product with d-1 1-dimensional outer products and works in all cases.

```
def outern(a):
    d = len(a)

    # If the elements are more than one-dimensional, assert that the extra
    # dimensions are all equal.
    s0 = a[0].shape
    for arr in a:
        assert s0[1:] == arr.shape[1:]

    out = a[0]
    for k in range(1, d):
        # Basically outer products. Checkout `numpy.outer`'s implementation for
        # comparison.
        out = numpy.multiply(
                # Insert a newaxis after k `:`
                out[(slice(None),) * k + (numpy.newaxis,)],
                # Insert a newaxis at the beginning
                a[k][numpy.newaxis],
                )
    return out
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use `numpy.einsum`

```
c = a[0]
for i in range(d-1): #adds one dimension in each iteration
    c = np.einsum('i...,...->i...', a[i+1],c)
```

This gives almost the same result as yours, but the axes are in reverse order:

```
c.swapaxes(0,2)==out #yields True
```

You can either reverse the first few axes or adapt the rest of you code, whatever works better for you.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like this little einsum gem would solve your problem:

```
out = np.einsum('i...,j...,k...->ijk...', *a)
```

Thats for the n=3 case, shouldnt be hard to generate the strings for the n-d case though. Though I suppose that the other einsum answer just posted might be just as performant for typical applications.

As for generating the einsum string from a string of axes chars of length ndim:

```
einsum_statement = ','.join(f'{a}...' for a in ax) + f'->{ax}...'
```

Think that should do..

Comment: You could replace `xy` by `...` to make it work more generally. Beyond that: Any idea how to generalize this expression for arbitrary `d`?

Comment: This solution doesn't work if `a = numpy.random.rand(d)`. This case could be intercepted with an `if`, I guess.